# Access Propertyware from salesforce app. Need help

Tags: community, salesforce1-app, integration, website-integration

I need to access [Propertyware](https://www.propertyware.com/) from my salesforce app. I know that it possible from their [official site blog](https://www.propertyware.com/blog/propertyware-open-api/). But unfortunately I didn't found any documentation about that. Anyone knows the details procedure and their requirement please share. Thank you advance.

Comment: It would be better to contact Propertyware directly as they should have the details of how to do this.

Comment: @DaveHumm thank you for your support. Actually I  already  mailed them yesterday and I don't get feedback my mail from them.